# c# Properties in Abstract Base Classes

Tags: c#, interface, properties, abstract

I have a strange problem that I could not solve. When I try to compile the following snipped I get this error:

'AbstractClass' does not implement interface member 'Property' (Compiler Error CS0535)

The online help tells me to make my AbstractClass abstract, which it is. Can anybody tell me where I went wrong?

Cheers Rüdiger

```
public interface IBase {
    string Property { get; }
}

public abstract class AbstractClass : IBase
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I am abstract";
    }
}

public class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass
{
    string Property { 
        get {
            return "I am Concrete";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your `AbstractClass` needs to provide an implementation for `Property` from the `IBase` interface, even if it's just abstract itself:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass : IBase
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I am abstract";
    }

    public abstract string Property { get; }
}
```

**Update:** Luke is correct that the concrete implementation will need to specify that `Property` is an override, otherwise you'll get a "does not implement inherited abstract member" error:

```
public class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass
{
    public override string Property { 
        get {
            return "I am Concrete";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that obviously solves it. I am still wondering why, it seems to be a break with the usual way Interfaces are handled in abstract classes.

Comment: How do you mean? A subclass of your abstract class shouldn't necessarily need to know that it implements IBase, it should just see virtual and abstract members that it may/must implement.

Comment: You'll also need to declare `Property` on `ConcreteClass` with the `override` modifier.

Comment: You are right dahlbyk. Seems I misunderstood the concept of interfaces and abstract classes. I thought only a concrete class needed to implement all abstract and interface members of base classes.

Comment: Well it works like that for interfaces implementing interfaces, but really the only special thing about an abstract class is that it can have abstract methods and not be constructed directly. All other rules apply.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add abstract implementation of the property to your AbstractClass :

```
public abstract class AbstractClass : IBase
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I am abstract";
    }

    public abstract string Property { get; }

}
```

And the override keyword to the Concrete class

Answer (score 2):

AbstractClass is supposed to implement IBase which contains Property, and you haven't implemented it

Answer (score 2):

You abstract class does *not* implement the interface `IBase`. Just add the property `Property` to `AbstractClass`.

```
public abstract String Property { get; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `Property` in `AbstractClass` so that it fulfills the `IBase` contract.

If you want `ConcreteClass` to be able to override `Property` then you should declare it as `abstract` or `virtual`. Then you'll need to declare the `ConcreteClass` implementation of `Property` with `override`.

```
    public interface IBase
    {
        string Property { get; }
    }

    public abstract class AbstractClass : IBase
    {
        public abstract string Property { get; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "I am abstract";
        }
    }

    public class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass
    {
        public override string Property
        {
            get
            {
                return "I am Concrete";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the ***IBase***-property ***Property*** like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass : IBase
{
    public override string Property()
    {
        return "This is the base-class implementation";
    }
}
```

Or make it **abstract**.

Answer (score 1):

You must implement Property property in abstract class.